# Bayes factor for one-tailed correlation (differences between results from Bayesfactor package in R vs JASP)

Tags: r, correlation, bayes-factors

I want to compute a Bayes factor for one-tailed correlation (n~600).
Using NHS, Pearson's r = 0.01 and p-value =0.42
With JASP, I get a one-tailed BF of 0.059, so strongly in favour of the null hypothesis.

In contrast, I get a very different result from the BayesFactor and I was wondering whether maybe I'm not using it right:

```
BF.directional = correlationBF(y=df$y,x=df$x,nullInterval=c(0,1),rscale=1)
BF=BF.directional[1]/BF.directional[2]
```

But the result of this is 1.5, so slightly in favour of r>0.

Surely the two results shouldn't be that widely different, I must be making a mistake?

I'd be very grateful for any pointers.

Comment: What's the motivation behind `BF=BF.directional[1]/BF.directional[2]`? `BF.directional` should already give you what you want, right?

Comment: I think what JASP is doing is to test the hypothesis "the correlation is greater than 0" against the hypothesis "the correlation is 0". This is also what `BF.directional[1]` should give you. `BF.directional[2]` tests the hypothesis "the correlation is smaller than 0" against the the hypothesis "the correlation is 0". When you compute the ratio `BF.directional[1]/BF.directional[2]` this tests the hypothesis "the correlation is greater than 0" against the hypothesis "the correlation is smaller than 0".

Comment: See also the discussion of directional tests [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BayesFactor/vignettes/manual.html#onesample)

Comment: oh I see, thanks @mesolimbic!! I think I misunderstood the manual and thought that the test I wanted was the ratio - as in that that would most correspond to a one-tailed p-value..

Comment: I've just been able to double-check (was ill since last week..) and indeed, the Bayes Factors now match (roughly) across JASP and R's Bayesfactor.